# I selected all of my model in edit mode and pressed H, the window on the bottom left says it hide it, but it is still showing the model

Tags: modeling, mesh

So I have a character, I want to hide every part except his eyes and tongue. I selected my model in object mode than hit tab, in edit mode I pressed L to select his eyes and tongue, I hit ctrl + I to invert it, it inverts it, then I hit H to hide the part that I inverted, the  window appears indicating that it is hidden, also the orange wireframe dissapears but the black lines that the character has in wireframe stays, so it is not looking hidden. Lastly, when I hit A, it just highlights the stuff that I want to see but I don't want to see the body. So it didn't hide the rest of the body "visually". But "technically" it did.

I selected all of my model in edit mode and pressed H, the window on the bottom left says it hide it, but it is still showing (also tried selecting a vertex of it after but it doesn't select anything of it)

I also tried doing with the menu and the search bar, it doesn't work.

- I also tried hiding a part of her hair which is another model, it works. So I'm guessing the problem is with the body mesh that I'm trying to hide.
- I am sure I don't have a duplicate of it.

I am using the latest version which is 3.1.0

Comment: If I understand correctly, your issue is that when you hide stuff in edit mode, you still see them in object mode? That's normal Blender behavior.

Comment: No when I try to hide my object in edit mode, I still see it in edit mode.

Comment: I think this is a bug in 3.1, I've noticed the same thing

Comment: If it's a bug, I hope that they see and fix it quickly

Comment: If it's a bug, then go to Help → Report a Bug.

Comment: The bug has been reported- https://developer.blender.org/T96567- you're welcome to add a comment explaining your experience with it

Comment: Yeah I just found out about it here https://developer.blender.org/T96080 thank you all for the answers